# Why does make_optional decay its argument type?

Tags: c++, type-traits, option-type, std, c++14

The (probably not C++14, probably Library TS) facility `make_optional` is defined ([in n3672](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html)) as:

```
template <class T>
  constexpr optional<typename decay<T>::type> make_optional(T&& v) {
    return optional<typename decay<T>::type>(std::forward<T>(v));
  }
```

Why is it necessary to transform the type `T` (i.e. not to just return `optional<T>`), and is there a philosophical (as well as practical) justification for using `decay` specifically as the transformation?

Comment: Because T can be an lvalue reference, and optional references aren't allowed.

Comment: @Simple so why not just `remove_reference`?

Comment: Presumably so you can't also make an `optional<T const>` or an `optional<T[N]>`, which would also have weird semantics.

Comment: +1 I was writting a universal reference based make-like function just twenty minutes before I have seen this question on the hot questions list. When tested the first time there was no `decay`, and I have spent ten minutes to realize that `decay`is needed to remove the cualifiers and universal-reference colapsing remains... **Why didn't post your question a hour before Ecatmur???** :P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A general purpose of `decay` is to take a type and modify it to be suitable for storage.

Take a look at these examples that `decay` makes work, while `remove_reference` would not:

```
auto foo( std::string const& s ) {
  if (global_condition)
    return make_optional( s );
  else
    return {};
}
```

or

```
void function() { std::cout << "hello world!\n"; }
auto bar() { return std::make_optional( function ); }
```

or

```
int buff[15];
auto baz() { return std::make_optional( buff ); }
```

An `optional<int[15]>` would be a very strange beast -- C style arrays do not behave well when treated like literals, which is what `optional` does to its parameter `T`.

If you are making a copy of data, the `const` or `volatile` nature of the source does not matter.  And you can only make simple copy of arrays and functions by decaying them to pointers (without falling back on `std::array` or similar). (in theory, work could be done to make `optional<int[15]>` work, but it would be lots of extra complications)

So `std::decay` solves all of these issues, and does not really cause problems, so long as you allow `make_optional` to deduce its argument's type instead of passing `T` literally.

If you want to pass in a `T` literally, there is no reason to use `make_optional` after all.

Comment: I just found http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2006/n2069.html which supports your assertion that the (a) purpose of `decay` is "to take a type and modify it to be suitable for storage". It's unfortunate that that purpose isn't expressed more explicitly in the standard.

Answer (score 15):

This is not new behaviour with `make_optional`; the utility functions `make_pair` and `make_tuple` behave in the same way. I can see at least two reasons to do this:

1. It may be undesirable or impossible to actually instantiate the template with the undecayed types.

   - If `T` is a function type, well, you just *can't* store a function inside a class, period; but you *can* store a function pointer (the decayed type).
   - If `T` is an array type: the resulting class is going to be "defective" because it can't be copied, owing to the fact that arrays are not copy-assignable. For `optional` the `value_or` member function can't be compiled at  all, because it returns `T`. Consequently you can't have an array type in an `optional` at all.
2. Not decaying the types may lead to unexpected behaviour.

   - If the argument is a *string literal*, I personally would expect the type contained to be `const char*` rather than `const char [n]`. This decay occurs in most places, so why not here?
   - If `v` is an lvalue then `T` will be deduced as an lvalue reference type. Do I actually want a pair containing a reference, for instance, just because one of the arguments was an lvalue? Surely not.
   - The type inside the pair or tuple or optional or whatever shouldn't acquire the cv-qualification of `v`. That is, say we have `x` declared as `const int`. Should `make_optional(x)` create a `optional<const int>`? No it shouldn't; it should create `optional<int>`.

Answer (score 7):

Just look at what `decay` does:

- Removes reference qualifiers—`T&` → `T`; no optional references, else you couldn’t reseat the `optional`, which needs to be assignable.
- For array types, removes extent—`T[42]` → `T*`; optional fixed-extent arrays aren’t that useful because each array size has a different type, and you can’t directly pass array types by value, necessary for the `value` and `value_or` member functions to work.
- For function types, adds pointer—`T(U)` → `T(*)(U)`; no optional function references, for similar reasons.
- Otherwise, removes cv-qualifiers—`const int` → `int`; no optional `const` values, again, else you couldn’t reseat the `optional`.

Comment: Try making `optional<int[35]>` work -- it is tricky, as arrays do not like being copied around outside of `struct`s.

Comment: On #1, optional references do exist in this specification, as essentially pointers: [reference implementation](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/blob/49f29c53d3f7b117cc33277e52b0a5b03a44570c/optional.hpp#L605).  They can be reassigned; see [notes on why it was decided to do so](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3527.html#optional_ref.rationale.assign).  Though just because you *can* have an optional reference doesn't make it a good default for `make_optional`, as per @Brian's answer for why this is following conventions in `make_tuple` and `make_pair`.